# Custom Collection View cell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a collection view with custom cells. I want to populate cells with images by fetching data from two places. One is default image array and another is array which is fetched after parsing `xml web services`. So the final array count is summation of default array count and array count of web services.

How to fetch the images in `cellForItemAt` method of collection view?
can Anyone help me out in this regard?

Comment: Both array contains the image?

Comment: yes both arrays contain image.The default array has 10 images so first 10 cells will be occupied by this 10 images ,from 11th image onwards the images will be fetched after xml parsing.

Comment: Might be best to join these two arrays.

Comment: @Saranya , At first `defaultArray.count` and in `XML parsing` make `dafaultArray.appent(newImage);collectionView.reloadData()`

Comment: i have appended both.I am not able to find out how to set the images to the collection view cell

Comment: In your custom cell view, add an outlet from the storyboard and use that to set images ...

Comment: I have a outlet to set images.My issue is how to write in cellForItemAt

Comment: I have written as let cell:SubCategoryCollectionViewCell = self.collectionview3.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryCollectionViewCell
    
    let item = defaultAnimalArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.subThumbImg?.image = UIImage(named: item as! String)
    return cell
This is for fetching default array images.now how to append the another array images to this cell.

Comment: post your code of custom cell view and cell for item at method

Comment: let cell:SubCategoryCollectionViewCell = self.collectionview3.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryCollectionViewCell
    
    let item = defaultAnimalArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.subThumbImg?.image = UIImage(named: item as! String)
    return cell

Comment: why are you not appending both arrays first and then give this array count in numberOfComponents method .. so you can access them all in cellForItemAt method ...

Comment: This is to fetch from default array,how to append this cell with also images from api .I have done parsing of xml and i have array count of that xml too.I have added both default and array from api too.So total array count is addition of both.But i dont know to fetch this array in cellForItemAt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From above Question**

```
let cell:SubCategoryCollectionViewCell = self.collectionview3.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier‌​: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryCollectionViewCell

if defaultAnimalArray.count-1 >= indexPath.row{ // ex: 0...7 
let item = defaultAnimalArray[indexPath.row]
cell.subThumbImg?.image = UIImage(named: item as! String)
}else{
//If now defaultAnimalArray.count = 8, indexPath = 8 , But array = 0...4, then,
let item = arrayFromAPI[indexPath.row-defaultAnimalArray.count] // 8-8 = 0
cell.subThumbImg?.image = UIImage(named: item as! String)
}
return cell
```

**Alternative 1:-**

Declare `defaultArray` as `var`.

Before `return defautlArray.count+arrayFromAPI.count` merge image array also . `i.e., defaultArray = defaultArray+arrayFromAPI` and return variable becomes `return defaultArray.count` as well as no change`cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

**Alternative 2:**

Declare `defaultArray` as `var` and Don't create `arrayFromAPI`. Just append new images in `defaultArray` in `XML Parsing`. After appending a new image `reload`  `UICollectionView` and also return variable becomes `return defaultArray.count`

**Alternative 3:**

With the same code , the `item` on `cellForItemAtIndexPath` becomes,

```
let item = defaultAnimalArray+arrayFromAPI[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: in Alternative 1,you meant defaultArray ,which is same as defaultAnimalArray in my code?

Answer (score 0):

set

```
collectionView.delegate = nil
 collectionView.dataSource = nil
```

Until you get all your images from `xml web services`. When you get all your data then update your `dataSource` array like you said

```
count = default array count + array count from web services
```

and then set `delegate` and `dataSource` of collectionView. Then in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell : UICollectionViewCell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "identifierCell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        /// Show Image Code here
        let url : String = dataSource[indexPath.row]
       if let _image = UIImage(named: url){ 
          // This If Will Load the image if it save locally
       } else {
         // Image does not save locally, download image from URL
       }

        return cell
    }
```

I have update my answer please look and tell me if you found anything difficult.
One thing you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) third party to download image from URL.

Comment: i have done till this point.how to set the image in cellForItemAt

Comment: Then please tell what type of images data you have in array dataSource?
Either you have images URL or you have images in your dataSource array.

Comment: i have both type images.one is from images url and another is image from default array which are images saved locally in project.I know to fetch the image url image too.But i dont know how to write in cellForItemAt

Comment: @ usman yes i have used sdwebimage third party to download image from UrL.Now i need to pass this image to another view controller.how can it be done ?

Comment: @Saranya You don't need to send Image to another viewController just simply send the URL to another viewController.